# Spritekti background music is playing for a second and then stopping

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game using spritekit and swift and am trying to add background music.

I am using this code:

```
let backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "gameMusic.m4a")
backgroundMusic.autoplayLooped = true
addChild(backgroundMusic)
```

My problem is that the music plays for just ~1 second and then stops. Then when I leave the scene, it plays for about the same length and then stops.

I am calling this code from my init function. I have got the same results when calling it from didMoveToView()

I tried other code I got from the googles and got the same result.

I also have this in my init function:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.runBlock(addGhost),
                SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
                ])
            ))
```

It seems like the music stops about the first time this is called.Might be related.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any timers on the hi thread that could be causing it to hang

Comment: I don't think there is any. One thing I found that when I set a breakpoint just after "addChild(backgroundMusic)" and then continue, the music will start playing.

Comment: going to need more code

Comment: You were right @RyanCollins. I had SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(1.0). I changed my transition to be instant and it worked.